# jQuery DataTables: How to get row index (or nNode) by row id of tr?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom, datatables

I have a dataTables `<table id="myTable">`. I would like to `fnUpdate()` and `fnDestroy()` my rows. every row has an id, eg: `<tr id="16">`.
To `fnUpdate()`/`fnDestroy()` the appropriate `<tr>`, I need to get that row's index. For this I try to use `fnGetPosition()`, but the way I try it is not the way to do it:

```
$("#myTable").fnGetPosition( $("#16") )
```

results in

> TypeError: nNode.nodeName is undefined [Break On This Error] var
>   sNodeName = nNode.nodeName.toUpperCase();

Which makes sense, as `fnGetPosition()` expexts nNode (in my case a HTMLTableRowElement).

How do I get the HTMLTableRowElement that has `id="16"` ?

EDIT:
A correct answer to my question is: `document.getElementById("16")`. Based on that, I would like to change my question to:

Why does

```
$("#myTable").fnGetPosition( document.getElementById("16") )
```

work, but

```
$("#myTable").fnGetPosition( $("#16") )
```

fails?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

document.getElementById() returns a DOM object, and everything on the DOM object will be inherently accessible.

JQuery's $('#...') returns a wrapper around a single DOM object OR a set of DOM objects (depending on the selector) and as such, it does not return the actual DOM Object. It makes it easier to work with DOM objects.

The reason you are getting that error in the second case would be that $(#...) is not actually a DOM object.

Comment: Oh, thank you. There's a get() method to retrieve the DOM elements matched by the jQuery object. So `$('#16').get()` should be equivalent to `document.getElementById("16")` for my purpose, or am I missing something?

Comment: Yep, according to Jquery API it returns the DOM element match by selector specified: http://api.jquery.com/get/

Answer (score 23):

For anyone who still has this problem, try this:

```
$("#myTable").fnGetPosition( $("#16")[0] )
```

To get the same result as `document.getElementById` you should access the first element in the jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

You sould do:

```
var oTable = $('#myTable').dataTable();
oTable.fnGetPosition( $("#myTable #16") );
```

Comment: Hm, this gives me the same TypeError. And I think `$("#myTable #16")` is no improvement over `$("#16")`, as #16 already is a unique identifier and I still don't have a HTMLTableRowElement to use for `fnGetPosition()`.

Comment: this wouldn't work as it has the same effect as his original code.